# Cannot git merge because git commit --amend

Tags: git, gitlab, git-amend

In master branch, I have the *Initial Commit* pushed gitlab

After that I create a new branch called "branchA"

I rename the initial commit with

```
git commit --amend -am Initial Commit v2
```

and do some modif and commit it

In this example, you can see something like that

```
master :
    - Initial Commit
branchA :
    - Initial Commit v2
    - Commit number 2
    - ....
```

I want to merge branchA into master how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't *rename* the initial commit.  Instead, you made a *new, different initial commit*.  You now have two initial commits:

```
$ mkdir tworoots
$ cd tworoots
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo example of multiple roots > README
$ git add README && git commit -m 'first root'
[master (root-commit) b89218d] first root
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ git branch branchA
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* b89218d (HEAD -> master, branchA) first root
```

Note how both branch names `master` and `branchA` select commit `b89218d`, which is my initial commit.

Now if I make a *new* initial commit:

```
$ echo forgot something > afile
$ git add afile
$ git commit --amend -m "second root"
[master c982f45] second root
 Date: Thu Feb 4 02:27:37 2021 -0800
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 README
 create mode 100644 afile
```

This new commit has a new hash ID, `c982f45` (your commits won't have this hash ID since this depends on my name, my email address, the date-and-time on my computer, and so on).  But the *first* root still exists, and `branchA` still finds it:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* c982f45 (HEAD -> master) second root
* b89218d (branchA) first root
```

It's hard to tell from this particular graph (due to the `--oneline` option) that these two commits are completely unrelated.  Run the same `git log` command but without `--oneline` and note that there's no connecting line *between* the commits, to see that.

If we now `git checkout branchA` and make more commits, they have the root commit of `branchA` as their (single) root commit:

```
$ git checkout branchA
Switched to branch 'branchA'
$ echo data go in files and the files go in commits > datafile
$ git add datafile
$ git commit -m 'add some data'
[branchA 12fe86a] add some data
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 datafile
```

A `git log` with our other usual options, but this time without `--all`, shows that `master`'s commit is not related to these commits:

```
$ git log --decorate --oneline --graph
* 12fe86a (HEAD -> branchA) add some data
* b89218d first root
```

An attempt to merge these two disjoint subgraphs produces an error (since Git 2.9):

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git merge branchA
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

You can force `git merge` to attempt the merge, as previous versions of Git would, by adding the `--allow-unrelated-histories` option.  However, without a good understanding of `git merge`, this is rarely a good idea.  In the example I built, it works.  If it works for you and does what you want, that's fine, but be sure it's really what you want.